# System.IO.FileNotFoundException only when run application on Windows 7

Tags: c#, exception

I'm having a problem with Loading font where it gives me exception if i run my program on Windows 7 but fine with Windows 10.

Here's the code i used:

```
public void LoadFont()
{
    string resource = "mynewproject.font_new.otf";
    Stream fontStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
    System.IntPtr data = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int)fontStream.Length);
    byte[] fontdata = new byte[fontStream.Length];
    fontStream.Read(fontdata, 0, (int)fontStream.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(fontdata, 0, data, (int)fontStream.Length);
    font.AddMemoryFont(data, (int)fontStream.Length);
    fontStream.Close();
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(data);
}
```

Then this is the code to load font: `label1.Font = new Font(font.Families[0], label1.Font.Size);`

I have embedded the font into project and set it as "Do not copy" and build action as "Embedded Resource", the program run fine and load the new font properly on my computer and some of my friends computer that use windows 10. However when i try running it on Windows 7 computer, it gives me this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found.
> at System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont(IntPtr memory, Int32 length)
> at mynewproject.MyForm.LoadFont()

Thanks and hope that this info actually makes sense.

Comment: You do not have the font family installed on the machine.

Comment: Try to install font manually using control panel to see if there are problems.

Comment: i use loadfont() because i want to use a font that not installed on the computer, it works fine on my and friends computer where the font not installed too. and for the second question, yes it still gives me exception if i installed the font locally (on windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

Well, so i found answer for this. It is weird that if i use .otf font it doesnt work but .ttf it does. I did some research and found that the use of System.Drawing support for OpenType fonts is limited :)

Comment: Hi takatto, thanks for putting the answer, that adds information. By the way, it should be .TTF  and not .TFF. The abbreviation stands for "True Type Font" as opposed to  OTF, the "Open Type Font". The OTF comes in two flavours, that is the old TTF and a system called CCF (Compact Font Format)

Comment: haha thanks for reminding me, it was a typo xd